# Index.html file not loading css

Tags: html, css

I've downloaded a website using wget. When I open the index.html file the css does not load. I noticed that the URL has the website name embedded in it when I open it on my local disk. For example:

file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/www.hickory.com.au/index.html

However the css folder is located in:

file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/css but is probably looking for

file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/www.hickory.com.au/css

How can I rectify this issue?

---

OK problem solved. Very dumb mistake by me.

Comment: You need to learn about relative and absolute paths in websites

Comment: I think I know the difference. The index file already has <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v=2.1" />.

Comment: if was of help, accept my answer please. as for the mistake, it happens daily for any programmer ..

Answer (score 1):

Make the paths relative.
So change something from file://Users to /css/

OLD:

```
file://Users/SomePath/AnotherPath/MyCss/somefile.css
```

NEW:

```
../MyCss/somefile.css
```

A "/" will tell the file to start from the base directory, this could be your base C: depending on what is reading the path.

A "../" will tell it to go up one folder.. so "Users/Folder/../" actually hits the Users folder.

**OR DO YOU MEAN**

That you have plenty of files and you want to correct this in every page, not just the index. As in how to have wget not do this or a simple batch process that will do it for every file?

**SECOND EDIT:**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Hickory Group</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<script src="js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Folder Layout:

```
C:\SomeBasicFolder\index.html
C:\SomeBasicFolder\favicon.ico
C:\SomeBasicFolder\css\style.css
C:\SomeBasicFolder\js\jquery-plugins\jquery.fancybox-1.3.4\jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
C:\SomeBasicFolder\js\libs\jquery-1.7.min.js
C:\SomeBasicFolder\js\modernizr-2.5.3.min.js
```

Comment: The index file already has <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v=2.1" />

Comment: the / at the front is telling it to go back to root... try removing the slash at the front.. Or give us a css files full path and the html file, then can give you the relative path to it.

Comment: The css file is located in

file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx//css/style.css%3Fv=2.1

but when I open it with Chrome the URL shows: file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/www.hickory.com.au/css/style.css%3Fv=2.1

Same with index file located in 

file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/index.html

but shows file:///Users/admin/Desktop/HickEx/www.hickory.com.au/index.html

Comment: By the sounds of it, your OS is having issues with the folder name...
First and for most, rename or move the contents to another location ... the www.hickory.com.au site name as a folder name is a bad one for certain operating systems like windows.

Comment: On my index.html file, the css file is referenced by  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v=2.1" />

Comment: If the css folder is in the same folder as the index.html, remove the front slash from the <link tag. so it should be just href="css/style.css" also dont worry about the ?v2.1 as that is a server side parameter

Comment: Updated answer again oi oi oi ;)